# Encode Columns based on Categorical Values

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, sparse-matrix

I am "learning" from the Kaggle IMDB movie database.  There is a "genre" column often with multiple categorical values i.e. Action, Drama, Sci-Fi. 
 
**Where the values in the genre column intersect with the column name, is there a neat way to set it to 1.**  i.e. if "genre" contains Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi, , set those columns values from NaN to 1.

I haven't seen one-hot type coding where the  a field has multiple categorical values. I started with a nested "For" block, but I got stuck about how to efficiently check the categorical values against the column names and set the values.  Any ideas? TIA

**SAMPLE DATA**
   --genre------------------------------ Drama --Adventure ---Sci-Fi ---Action
2  Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi -----NaN-------NaN------------NaN------NaN
3  Drama-----------------------------NaN-------NaN------------NaN------NaN
4  Drama-----------------------------NaN-------NaN------------NaN------NaN

**I want it to look like this:**

--genre------------------------------ Drama --Adventure ---Sci-Fi ---Action
2  Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi -----NaN-------1---------------1----------1
3  Drama-----------------------------1------------NaN-----------NaN------NaN
4  Drama-----------------------------1------------NaN-----------NaN------NaN

Comment: `df.genre.str.get_dummies(',')`?

Comment: I've used get-dummies on a dataframe, never before on a series, thanks for the help and pointing out the "sep" parameter.

Comment: Not that I expect to a one-liner, but curious if there is a brief "iter" type solution too